# Replacing Images in Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, xml, icons, navigation-drawer

Below is my `activity_main_drawer.xml`(List of `Navigation Drawer`). I need to replace the icons with `CustomImages`. Below given icons are Vector images. I tried to replace some images in `drawable`. No errors thrown but images not appearing in the `navigation drawer` list.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_soup"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Soup" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_salads"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Salads" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_main_course"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="MainCourse" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_brktifdin"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Breakfast | Tiffin | Dinner" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_snacks"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:title="Snacks" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_beverages"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:title="Beverages" />
</group>
```

Comment: and how do you trying to change the images? Provide some code

Comment: check this link http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/

Comment: What is the android version of the device of test ?

Comment: hii please check values > drawables.xml file and check there the pngs are you puting in menu are available in drawables.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is size of the image am using. I have reduced my Image size to Icon size and its working. Below is my workings. Thank U all for your responses.

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_beverages"
        android:icon="@drawable/sample.jpg"
        android:title="Beverages" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Drawable folder Delete  `@drawable/ic_menu_camera.xml`from your drawable folder.

Use direct icon from Drawable like this `@mipmap/ic_launcher`. For testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove all previous default PNGs from your drawable Folder(Directory) and then remove all resources from **drawables.xml file under values folder**

2.again add all images.png from using vector and add it in to menu.xml